# I don't have openssh-server, but I can ssh to localhost

Tags: 12.04, ssh

openssh-server is not installed on my computer, but I can ssh to localhost or from another computer I can ssh to my computer. It means there is another ssh-server running on my computer. How can I find it? Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The ssh server is in the `ssh` package.

Comment: @January the `ssh` package is just a metapackage that depends on the `openssh-{client,server}` packages.

Comment: @Oli good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is listening on a port with `netstat`. I'm using awk to trim that down a bit to just things running on port 22 and sort to strip out duplicates.

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | awk '/:22/ {printf "%d\n", $7}' | sort -u
979
```

The output is the ID of the process.

We can further explore this by looking at the `/proc/` table for this process. I'm using the above output but you should substitute your running process in.

```
$ sudo readlink -f /proc/979/exe
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

To find out which package that belongs to we  can then just:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/sshd
openssh-server: /usr/sbin/sshd
```

And we can combine that into on massive ugly command:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | awk '/:22/ {printf "%d\n", $7}' | sort -u | while read p; do dpkg -S $(sudo readlink -f /proc/$p/exe); done
openssh-server: /usr/sbin/sshd
```